# Authenticating Excel Task Pane app to CRM Online

Tags: excel, odata, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to write an Excel Task Pane app to interact with CRM Online - to take data from the Excel worksheet, process it and push it into a CRM entity record.  My Excel users are on Office 365, as is CRM Online (obviously).  We are using ADFS 2.0.

The specific problem I am experiencing is that I do not know how to get authentication to work for the Task Pane app: specifically, to the OData endpoint via JavaScript.  Authentication is not my area, so I don't know how to precisely phrase this next requirement, but as we are using Office 365/CRM Online/ADFS then I need to use the logged-in user's Windows AD credentials to authenticate the request.

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to authenticate the Task Pane app directly with CRM Online, and I would like to know if that is known to be true, and if not what method(s) I can use.

I do know that there is a hack for indirect authentication published by a couple of people (http://survivingcrm.com/2013/12/connecting-crm-online-odata-feed-excel-2013-power-query/ or http://www.crmconsult.co.uk/connecting-to-crm-20112013-with-odata-in-excel-2013/) which authenticates the user via the CRM plug-in and then allows other OData connections to succeed - but it doesn't work for me, and I'm averse to rolling out functionality to users which relies on back-door methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended used using SOAP in VBA instead of oData in the Task Pane, which meant I was able to use Jason Lattimer's hard work from http://jlattimer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-vba.html - I don't think there is any way I would have figured out the Authentication piece without that post, so many thanks to him.